# Copy a file to a remote server and load it into a MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel, load-data-infile

I have a file on a computer that is updated little by little and I want to upload this to a remote server and put it in the MySQL database that is on that same server. The server is running CENTOS 7 and the computer is running Windows. Already checked several pages and many searches in google and finally ended up with this code:

```
import base64
import paramiko

import pymysql

from paramiko import SSHClient
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import pandas as pd


def sendFileFromTo(client, orig, dest):
    sftp = client.open_sftp()
    sftp.put(orig, dest)
    sftp.close()


def exe(client, command):
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    for line in stdout:
        print('... ' + line.strip('\n'))

    def main():

    client = paramiko.SSHClient()

    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(host, port=port, username='root', password='pass')
    print("Connected")
    #exe(client, 'ls')

    sendFileFromTo(
        client,
        orig,
        dest)

    print("File Sent")

    client.close()

    print("SSH CLOSED")

    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (host, port),
        ssh_username='root',
        ssh_password='pass',
        remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306),
            local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3305)) as tunnel:

        print("STARTING MYSQL")
        with pymysql.connect(host=tunnel.local_bind_host, user='root',
                             passwd='rootSolar', db='TEST',
                             port=tunnel.local_bind_port, local_infile=True) as conn:

            print("LOADING QUERY")
            #query = '''USE TEST'''
            # print(query)
            #data = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
            query = '''LOAD DATA INFILE '/root/copied_file' INTO TABLE RS FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 4 ROWS (@time,record,Radiacion,Radiacion_UVA) SET time = STR_TO_DATE(@time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');'''
            # print(query)
            #data = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                cur.executemany(query)
                conn.escape_string()
                conn.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I have right now creates an ssh connection with the remote server to upload and overwrite the file, close it and create an ssh tunnel for connection to MYSQL and the database. The host and port variables have the values of the remote server for the ssh connection but since it is a public address I will not give those details.

The code works well with other MySQL queries but specifically with this program hangs and the terminal is frozen. Nor can I use ctrl + c to close the process, I have to close the terminal to be able to close it